# Is it a good practise to use React Decorators?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, javascript-decorators

I am just curious which practice is better and more usable nowadays, is it cleaner to write decorators in React or not?

The example of difference below:

```
@reduxForm({form: 'exampleForm', onSubmit: formOnSubmit('example-from-action/')})
export default class ExampleForm extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div></div>
  }
}
```

```
    class ExampleForm extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return <div></div>
          }
    }

    export default reduxForm({form: 'exampleForm', onSubmit: formOnSubmit('example-from-action/')})(ExampleForm);
```

Comment: I believe decorators are only possible in ts... And they're still in experimental phase.

Comment: @bravemaster I am working on one project with React and it has decorators, but it requires an extra package ```babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy```. I never worked with decorators in react before, so just curious why people are using them :)

Comment: @Balvaras I have never used decorators in react project, but have used them in a typescript express project. Javascript does not have traits. You can use decorators instead. The experience was pretty good...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, for the moment, it's still a bad idea to use decorator in javascript.

They're still a stage 2 proposal: https://github.com/tc39/proposals.

According to this process https://tc39.es/process-document/, it does not mean it will surely be included in the language.

If you do use decorators, it will be probably with either typescript or babel ( legacy-decorators). You might have to change some code later to fix if the actual feature in the language does not match, or if it's rejected.

Comment: It's a stage 3 already.